# Using C to send keyboard events

Tags: c++, windows, keypress, sendinput

So I am using Java and with that I can use Robot to do key presses. Now parts of the software we want to use keypresses for do not accept these (they do nothing) but the keyboard does work.

So the first thing I tried was using a C dll library which sends the keys using SendInput. If I use them on a website like https://keycode.info/ they work better then the Robot key presses (they show more information, more similar to actual keyboard presses.

However, still not all software registers the input. Most do so I know they are working "properly" but for some applications they still pose an enigma. If have used some keyboard detection software, which works fine when I press the buttons on my actual keyboard but both the java Robot library nor the C SendInput show any activity in that software.

What am I missing? (minimal working example)

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

INPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
ip.ki.wVk = 0;
ip.ki.wScan = MapVirtualKey(0x41, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;

SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

sleep(100);

ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
return;
}
```

I also played with the time between pressing and releasing but it did not seem to matter (for some application it does, but for the keyboard tester it did not.)

I really do want to simulate the keyboard keys but I am not sure where to look for it, SendInput seemed the lowest level I could get, but it seems I am mistaken, any ideas or solutions?

Comment: You have C++ and C tags, but your code appears to be javascript.  You're environment is a browser?

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: @jwdonahue I added C and C++ tags because this is C code. I clearly explain this in my post as well. Please read the full post before commenting, this does not really help me or anyone that will read this post. I also do not see ANY javascript anywhere so I am a bit surprised about your reaction. Hopefully you will read my full post and have some insights for me. On-topic help is appreciated! With kind regards

Comment: @jwdonahue The code is working fine but as my post explains, it is not low-level enough or not keyboard enough to simulate that. So my code, even with a full application showing the thing, I need something else probably. The code I shared should be enough for people to understand. I think most can add a simple main wrapper if need be. But I probably need a different approach, I added the code just to be sure somebody spots something I might have done wrongly or missed. But all in all I think I need a differetn approach not known to me and which I could not find searching Google or SO

Comment: Please read [ask] and post an [mcve]. Most of us don't care what you think is easy for us to do.

Comment: And I'll ask one more time.  Is the target execution environment a browser?  And please pick either C or C++, they are not the same language.

Comment: I have removed the C tag (although this code works in both), I added the main function so you should be able to run the code without modification (minimal reproducible example) Not sure adding the main line actually added value but as my goal is to see if someone can help me I will happily add it.

As for the question about the browser. The target is software that can handle keyboard input. So yes browsers, but also Windows itself, but also Microsoft visual studio, Android Studio, Photoshop etc.). An example of software not handling it is OBS (Open Broadcast Studio) where the others do.